# True Or False. $P(AB) = P(A)P(B|A)$

Tags: probability

This is a homework question I am confused about.

For each statement, determine if it is True or False.

a) $P(AB) = P(A)P(B|A)$

b) $0 < P(A|B) < 1$

Allow me to explain my thinking. The question does not assert whether $A$, $B$ are independent or dependent events. In my notes, I know that if they are independent, then $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$, but if they are dependent, then $P(AB) = P(A)P(B|A)$, making the first statement true. Is there a difference in notation when referring to $P(AB)$? As in, does $P(AB) = P(A \cap B)$. I read somewhere that $P(AB)$ is the same as $A$ AND $B$ which is an intersection.

Now for b), this one seems extremely intuitive and could be overthinking. Essentially in our course we are taught that the probability of an event from our sample space can be represented between $0$ and $1$. So is the question just asserting that the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ exists between $0$ and $1$? In that case wouldn't it be true?

Comment: For part $b$, what happens when $A=B$?  Or when $A=B^c$?

Comment: $P(AB)$ is odd notation, but I’d guess it means $P(A\cap B).#

Comment: Yes, that sounds mostly right to me, but watch out for $\leq$ vs <.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor, In that case, wouldn't it be false since $P(A|B)$ can be equal to 0 or 1 (impossible vs certain), and the notation only holds for $<$ instead of $\leq$?